# Laravel 5.2 - How to logout a user from all of his devices

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis, laravel-5

When a user logged out from a perticular device I want to logout from all the device he has logged in till now . How I do it in Laravel.

I have used Redis for keeping the userId in Session by installing   "predis/predis": "~1.0"

And Here is my controller for SignIn and Logout:

```
  public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {       

       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) ) {

       $redis = \Redis::connection();   
        $userId=Session::getId();
        $redis->sadd('users:sessions:'.$userId,Session::getId());
          return redirect()->route('main');

        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }



public function getLogout()
{
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $userId=Session::getId();
    $userSessions = $redis->smembers('user:sessions:' . $userId);
    $currentSession = Session::getId();
    foreach ($userSessions as $sessionId) {
         if ($currentSession == $sessionId) {
      continue; 

            }
             $redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);
            $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);

        }
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('main');
}
```

It's successfully get logged in and also logged out but it doesn't kill all the session in other devices.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Just try to change line position on getLogout function :  $redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId); $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);

Comment: There is a problem with my redis Connection so same Error I'm getting after changing those lines.

Comment: hm I think you should use `$userId=Auth::user()->id;` instead of `$userId=Session::getId();`  because second gives you session id but not user 
I think problem, with this so in your case you save every time only one session id

Comment: I have changed to `$userId=Auth::user()->id;` But same problem I'm getting means it successfully logged out but couldn't kill the other session with the same user Id.
I'm using redis in windows and while running the project I also run `redis-server.exe`

Comment: at first you should check if you can write to redis, then check that you have sessions ids in redis (you can do it from console) if records exist and code still not work try to add logs or var_dump() dd() etc. and see what you actually get in code. I think code should look like this https://gist.github.com/Dyachenko/4a75555b596ed2ee928b4b9e0ec1f861

Comment: In `$redis->sadd` where does redis save the session data?
   means while logout it checks everytime the already save sessionId But in my database table there is no sessionId stored. 
Actually I'm newbie to redis..That's why I'm asking..I have written your code but same thing I'm getting, it doesn't logout from other device.

Comment: hm in config you set session driver redis `SESSION_DRIVER=redis`? if config right run redis-cli.exe and then command 'monitor' in this mode you can see all redis actions (write data read etc.) and then try to login after login check console and find record with `SET users:sessions:somehash`  then try to logout and check how many records with DEL command

Comment: does Redis session those session Id in DB?
I think there is a problem with while checking with the sessionId because I while I dd() the o/p   `$userSessions = $redis->smembers('user:sessions:' . $userId);` I see empty Array.

Comment: in your config `SESSION_DRIVER=redis` right?

Comment: YEs `CACHE_DRIVER=redis SESSION_DRIVER=redis`

Comment: can you do follow: Log in your app,  Run `redis-cli.exe`, Run command  `KEYS` and show what you have. maybe skype or some chat for faster communication because comments are slow way)) (my skype you can find in profile )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So issue was with typo in redis key name,
for write data used 
`$redis->sadd('users:sessions:'.$userId,Session::getId());`
where key's prefix `'users:sessions:'` and for get data used 
`$redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);` where key's prefix `'user:sessions:'`
Thats why code didn't work and `dd()` returned empty array.

so correct code looks like this

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{    

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) ) {
        $redis = \Redis::connection();   
        $userId=Session::getId();
        $redis->sadd('user:sessions:'.$userId,Session::getId());
        return redirect()->route('main');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}



public function getLogout()
{
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $userId=Session::getId();
    $userSessions = $redis->smembers('user:sessions:' . $userId);
    $currentSession = Session::getId();

    foreach ($userSessions as $sessionId) {
         if ($currentSession == $sessionId) {
             continue; 
         }
            $redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);
            $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);
        }
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('main');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a suggestion/workaround for Your problem:

Working with sessions which are not stored in database is pain in a**, so You have to think differently in order to solve the problem. The different solution would be to record user id and time, when user logout. Then create middleware which will disconnects user if connection is older than last logout date. And thats all.

---

My prototype would look like so:
In `postSignIn` method line below will record user (session) login date: `app('request')->session()->put('login_date', time());`

In `getLogout` method line below will record user logout date globally:
`\Cache::put('last_logout_'.\Auth::id(), time());`

And final touch would be middleware with code similar to this:

```
if ($user = \Auth::user()) {
    $login_date       = app('request')->session()->get('login_date');
    $last_logout_date = \Cache::get('last_logout_' . $user->id, time() + 100);
    if ($login_date < $last_logout_date) {
        \Auth::logout();
        //redirect, error message...
    }
}
```

---

Full code:

Methods:

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
        app('request')->session()->put('login_date', time());

        return redirect()->route('main');
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function getLogout()
{
    \Cache::put('last_logout_' . \Auth::id(), time());
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect()->route('main');
}
```

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LogoutIfExpired
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($user = \Auth::user()) {
            $login_date       = app('request')->session()->get('login_date');
            $last_logout_date = \Cache::get('last_logout_' . $user->id, time() + 100);
            if ($login_date < $last_logout_date) {
                \Auth::logout();

                return redirect()->route('main');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with the full code?
if possible..May b I'm not getting what you actually meant to say!

Comment: @x69 No problem, I appended my answer.

Comment: Also make sure Your `QUEUE_DRIVER` is not `sync`.