# Is there any way to check if Laravel Session with particular SessionId exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When the user changes a password, I want to invalidate all other sessions (except current one) of it, thus logout the user from all rest devices, to do so, I am following [this answer's strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937908/6168395) with `file driver`, by storing ONLY user's `sessionIds` in database to track user's sessions.

Now, With **Laravel 5.1**, we can get SessionId with `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::getId()` ([API](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Session/Store.html#method_getId)), but is there any way to check if Session with any particular `sessionId` exists or not?

I've seen Laravel, creates session files by naming them with their `sessionId`, so as a last option, I can check if `file_exists(sessionId)`, but I wanted to know if there was any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel 5.6 and up it allows you to this out of the box. [You can read the documentation on it here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices) but this is the gist of it.

First, add the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` to your middleware stack. It should already be there but commented out (that's how it ships in Laravel). Then, when a user changes their password you should pass it into `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password)`.

Laravel keeps a hashed copy of the password in the session, so when the password is changed the middleware will forcefully log out any sessions that have the old password hash. It would be much better to use this built-in functionality instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: If upgrading to 5.6 isn't an option for you I would suggest you browse through the source of the `AuthenticateSession` middleware and the `Auth` guard and copy the relevant code into your project. It still saves you having to reinvent the wheel and means you can just rip that code out if you do ever move to 5.6.