# How to invalidate particular session in Laravel (with user using remember me feature)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Using **Laravel 5.1 & 'file' Session Driver**,

I'm trying to provide facility to user to track their sessions and invalidate them anytime they wish by keeping a record of their `session_id` within the database. With Database, I mean, I maintain a table called `user_sessions` which associates `user_id` with their `session_id` (obtained by `Session::getId()`).

So, to invalidate Session, I tried the following code,

```
$sessionId = Session::getId();
Session::setId($sessionId);
Session::invalidate();
```

and it works perfectly fine, for the case where, **where user does not uses Remember Me feature.**

For the case where user uses **Remember Me feature**, this above code **does not work**, So, I additionally, tried setting `remember_token` field to `null` as specified here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693568/6168395), but with this, all sessions of the user get destroyed including the current one.

Comment: It would help if you provided some more details on what you're doing e.g. what session driver are you using, how are you associating session ids with users etc.

Comment: I've updated the question, please check.

Comment: I don't think you need to invalidate the remember token. The token is not there to associate a user with a session but to automatically create a new one if there's no session currently alive.

Comment: Invalidating just the session, when the user selects **remember me**, does not work. Laravel creates a new session for the user using stored remember cookie, which is why I tried invalidating remember token as well.

Comment: When you're doing this you need to make sure that there is still a session associated with the user otherwise you will lose any session information, i.e., never invalidate the current session.

Comment: Currently for testing, Yes, I am manually checking if session which I am trying to invalidate, exist or not.

Comment: @apokryfos, any way you'd suggest to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

Session::forget('YOUR_SESSION_ID');
```

If you want to get the current session Id:

```
Session::driver()->getId();
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I think `Session::forget()` accepts `key` within the session. Still, I tried what you said, and it **didn't work**

Comment: May be you can try `Session::regenerate()`

Comment: But why would I want to regenerate the `session_id` when I **already have one** and I just want to invalidate it?

Comment: The `Session::forget` method doesn't forget the session, but a key stored in the session, this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are meant to be short-lived. If you want something a bit more permanent you can use some sort of a long term user settings table.

Create a table `user_settings`:

```
id (PK), user_id(FK users table), settings(BLOB?), created_at, updated_at
```

Add a model:

```
class UserSetting extends Model {
      public function user() {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
      }
}
```

You can also associate the user with these via :

```
 class User extends Model {
 //...
     public function settings() {
         $this->hasMany(UserSetting::class);
     }
 }
```

You can then get all user sessions via:

```
 User::find($u)->settings();
```

When a user logs in regularly or automatically via a remember token a `Login` event is fired.

You can listen to this in your event service provider:

```
\Event::listen(\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class, function ($event) {
       // Here you can load the last settings in the session if you want e.g. 
       session(['current_settings' => $event->user->settings()->latest()->value('id') ]); 
        // or you can just make a new entry: 
        $settings = new UserSettings();
        $event->user->settings()->save($settings);
        session(['current_settings' => $settings->id ]);
});
```

Note that you will have to manually persist things that need persisting instead of just putting them in the session.

Comment: I got the concept, and I like it. With this, I'll be able to track sessions using settings table that you have answered, and thus will be able to invalidate obtained sessions based on this. But again the same question arises, that, **How do I invalidate those sessions (_log out a user from those devices_) where user checked `remember me` checkbox.?**

Comment: When a user logs out the [`Logout`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/56a58e0fa3d845bb992d7c64ac9bb6d0c24b745a/src/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Logout.php) event is triggered so you can delete some or all sessions based on the user of that event.

Comment: I do not want **when a user logs out**, I am asking for an addon to that. When I am tracking sessions and listing them to the user, then I am thinking to provide a **button** to that list, saying _invalidate this session_, which when clicked, that particular session should be invalidated. **Example:** There are three sessions of the user, 1. Windows-Chrome, 2. Android-Chrome, 3. Mac-Safari. Now say user is currently logged in from 2nd one (Android-Chrome) and wishes to invalidate his 3rd session (Mac-Safari), then he should be able to do it. This feature, is what I am tring to achieve.

Comment: Ok I think I get you now. If you associate `UserSetting` with a specific Session active on another device then the button can be used to delete a row in that table and you can listen to the [`Authenticated`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Authenticated.php) event to ensure the UserSetting associated with the current session is still there otherwise force a logout with `Auth::logout()` if it's not.

Comment: Exactly! Now how do I achieve this **force logout** when user checks `remember me` checkbox, **is the problem**. Without `remember me`, I can easily invalidate the file-driver based session by just deleting that particular session file. With, `remember me` cookie within user's browser, it re-logins the user and a fresh new session is again created, so deleting the older session becomes useless.