# Remotly destroy user session from admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am building an admin panel.
Where i give the option to blacklist a user.
If the user is logged in at the time of blacklisting, how can i destroy his session.
his session has the following keys- user_id, username, is_login.
I want to set the is_login to false.
I am working with php

Comment: what is your authentication method?

Comment: if the user enter his login id and password correctly the the session variables are set. in every page he visit session variables are checked

Comment: i just want to change his session variable value. i have the user id of the user. and the same user id is stored in the session

Comment: how are the session variables generated and for how long are they valid for? I imagine your backend checks that the session variables are valid, you can check that the user that is trying to access server credentials does not exist on your blacklist

Comment: If your backend keeps a copy of all the valid session tokens you can also just remove that token.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 - Logout a user from all of his devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875866/laravel-5-logout-a-user-from-all-of-his-devices)

Comment: Change sessions to database and query and delete the sessions. Then update authentication to check user is blacklisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that by :

- add field at users table `blocked`
- add `middleware`  that checks  for `blocked` value of user
- if true fire `Auth::logout();`

for more info kindly check the following article [3 Ways to Delete User in Laravel: Block, Hide or Hard-Delete?](https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/3-ways-to-delete-user-in-laravel-block-hide-or-hard-delete/)

Comment: the i need to make a database query in every request

Comment: btw, i got a solution, and thanks you all for your support

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create banned_at column at users table.

**Step 2:** Create middleware for this For example: CheckBanned

In CheckBanned.php Middleware

```
public function handle ( $request, Closure $next )
{
    if ( auth ()->check () && auth ()->user ()->banned_at )
    {
        auth ()->logout ();

        $message = __ ( 'auth.banned_error' );

        return redirect ()->route ( 'login' )->with ( 'error',$message );
    }

    return $next( $request );
}
```

**Step 3:** Add middleware to app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
        ....
        ....
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckBanned::class,
        ....
        ],
     ....
     ....
],
```